# mutliindex dask dataframe to 2d dask array

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have `n` CSVs that each have an identical format (same `k` number of features). I'm hoping to construct a 2d dask array `n` sample by `k` features dask array for PCA, model building, etc.

I read them into a dask dataframe using dd.read_csv("*_all_csvs.csv"), at which point my dask dataframe is basically just `sample`, `feature`, `feature_value`. Is there an efficient way to convert the multi-indexed dataframe to a 2d dask array of `n` samples by `k` features?

Comment: It sounds like you want to start with group-by on the sample column. Regular SO users will suggest that you should try something first, because "why does this code behave the way it does" is much easier to answer than "how do I...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following might work:

```
df = dd.read_csv('*.csv')
df = df.categorize()
df = df.get_dummies()
x = df.values
```

This isn't tested though, so you'll probably run into issues.  I recommend trying this first with Pandas and providing an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future questions.